Different outputs depending on different IDE used?
So I'm learning Python in a Coursera Google course, which provides instructional code inside a Jupyter notebook page. But in addition to the Jupyter page, I primarily use the IDLE Shell and scratchpad (downloaded from Python.org) as my main IDE to run programs. The output is generally identical when copy/pasting code between these two environments.
But this one code chunk produces different output between the two environments. In the Jupyter it provides all the pairings, line-by-line, all the way down. But the IDLE Shell does not print out anything; its totally blank, despite being a precise copy/paste. I can't make sense of these different results. I have really tried to make sure there was no typo anywhere. Any ideas? Thanks
dominoes = []
for left in range(7):
    for right in range(left, 7):
        dominoes.append((left, right))
dominoes


Yes, that makes sense, and I thought it was odd that the Jupyter environment had somehow bypassed this, and printed without ever being told to print. So when pasting the same exact code into the IDLE Shell, I did  implement the print statement/function at the very end prior to posting this question here earlier. And it did print it in the Shell as commanded. But here it delivers all the output in one continuous line that wrapped once. This is different than the Jupyter notebook which printed one iteration per line for all 28 lines.

This is normal behavior of a ipython/jupyter console.  When a variable appears alone or last on a line (or cell), it is displayed.  And the display uses a pretty-print.  For a long enough list, that is one element per line.   x=foobar doesn't display anything; foobar does.

This would work fine in a REPL, where the value of the last expression usually gets implicitly printed out.
However, to print output in general, you'd want print(dominoes) instead of dominoes.

Building on this great answer...For fancier types of output, use display, such as display(df) for a Pandas dataframe, when it is not the last expression of a cell. See here, plus the comments in that reply, for options for InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity you can set at the top of your notebook to not just use the default last expression in a Jupyter cell. In general, you can think of the last expression in IPython or Jupyter as special in how it is handled.

try printing the dominoes variable
print(dominoes)

Jupyter automatically prints the output when you write a variable name in one line, but it is not the case in other shell or IDEs. you need to explicitly tell them to print the output on screen

Yes that makes sense, and I thought it was odd that the Jupyter environment had somehow bypassed this, and printed without ever being told to print. So when pasting the same exact code into the IDLE Shell, I did  implement the print statement at the very end of the chunk prior to posting this question here earlier. And it did print it in the Shell as commanded. But here it delivers all the output in one continuous line that wrapped once. This is different than the Jupyter page which printed one iteration per line for all 28 lines. Thanks for explaining that difference between the environments.

It will would with any IDE.
Easier way to use one-liner.
Snippet:
dominoes = [(left, right)for left in range(7)for right in range(left, 7)] 
print(dominoes)


If one pastes the statements one at a time into IDLE Shell, or the standard PyREPL, they are executed one at a time and you get the result expected.
>>> dominoes = []
>>> for left in range(7):
...     for right in range(left, 7):
...         dominoes.append((left, right))
... 
>>> dominoes
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)]

If one pastes all three at once into Shell, one gets SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement.  Shell does not currently try to separate multiple pasted statements.
If one pastes all three at once into the current 3.14.0a1+ PyREPL, the last line is indented the same as the previous statement, resulting in two statements and the list being printed in each iteration of the double loop.
If one pastes all three at once into an editor, IDLE's or other, and, as other said, wrap dominoes with print(), the code executes (in batch mode) as expected, with the output above.
